# Why does from scipy import spatial work, while scipy.spatial doesn't work after import scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to use `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` in my code. I can import the `spatial` submodule if I do something like `import scipy.spatial` or `from scipy import spatial`, but if I simply `import scipy` calling `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(...)` results in the following error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spatial'`.

What is wrong with the second approach?

Comment: @alKid and @falsetru gave good answers, and you should accept one of them. To explain why this is the case for `scipy` in particular, the reason that we do not import all subpackages is that there are a lot of them and many have large extension modules that consume quite a bit of time to load. Most programs don't need all of scipy loaded, so that would add a lot of extra overhead to all programs if we always imported all subpackages.

Comment: This answer given by "alKid" and "falsetru" are not factually correct and rather misleading. The reason lies in the __init__ files of the package. The __init__ of scipy does not import its modules while the __init__ of some other packages like numpy imports its modules.

See better answers at the duplicate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379576/why-cannot-i-use-sp-signal-by-import-scipy-as-sp

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Importing a package does not import submodule automatically. You need to import submodule explicitly.

For example, `import xml` does not import the submodule `xml.dom`

```
>>> import xml
>>> xml.dom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dom'
>>> import xml.dom
>>> xml.dom
<module 'xml.dom' from 'C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\__init__.pyc'>
```

There's an exception like `os.path`. (`os` module itself import the submodule into its namespace)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path
<module 'ntpath' from 'C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 14):

That's because scipy is a *package*, not a module. When you import a package, you don't actually load the modules inside, and thus `package.module` causes an error.

However, `import package.module` would work, because it loads the module, not the package.

This is the standard behavior for most import statements, but there are a few exceptions.

Here is the same case for `urllib` in Python 3:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__initializing__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'error', 'parse', 'request', 'response']
```

See? there is no submodules there. To access its submodule, we ask for the submodule:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>>
```

Hope this simple explanation helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use following line to import:

```
import scipy.spatial # worked.
```

instead of

```
import scipy # not working
```

I tried and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Use scipy version 1.2.1 to solve this issue......

Comment: Always elaborate your answer. In this case, you can say what betterment is available in 1.2.1 version or the bug fixed, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, your answer both doesn't answer the OP's question of "What is wrong with the second approach?" and it is incorrect. Even with scipy 1.4.1 the second approach still results in `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'spatial'`