# import PyQt4 does not include PyQt4.QtCore or QtGui

Tags: python, pyqt4

Why do neither of these statements import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork or any of the others?
I've searched so long and can't find anyone to answer such a simple question. Or at least that's what I think it is.

```
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import *
```

Instead I have to do:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *
```

Plus a bunch more. Any shortcuts to grab them all?

**Edit**: My solutions was to go through the libraries that I was using (for Py2exe) and just copy their imports. That worked. Still, but not as tedious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does from scipy import spatial work, while scipy.spatial doesn't work after import scipy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071715/why-does-from-scipy-import-spatial-work-while-scipy-spatial-doesnt-work-after)

Comment: @falsetru I don't know if its a duplicate. The asker wants to know if they can import *everything* in the PyQt4 namespace into the global namespace.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, OP also asked **why** `from pkg import *` does not import subpackages.

Comment: @falsetru A true, I glossed over that sentence and jumped right to "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to import all PyQt4 classes into a single namespace, you can do:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt
```

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use `import *`, namespaces exist for a good reason.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)

Import the modules you need, in the modules you need them in.

This code might require a few extra letters, but you'd only know `QUrl` was a Qt module by convention, not surety.

```
 from PyQt import QtCore
 u = QtCore.QUrl
```

The above code means when you are examining the second line you know *for certain* that it is a Qt object from a specific module and nothing else.