# why cannot I use sp.signal by import scipy as sp?

Tags: python, scipy, enthought

I would like to use `scipy.signal.lti` and `scipy.signal.impulse` function to calculate the transfer function. I import the `scipy` module in the following way.

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
```

However, when I type the following scripts,

```
tf = sp.signal.lti(numH, denH)
```

The Kernel gives an error:

```
---> 10 tf = sp.signal.lti(numH, denH)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal'
```

I tried another way to import the signal module,

```
from scipy.signal import lti, step, impulse
```

Then, the script works,

```
tf = lti(numH, denH)
```

So, my questions is, must we import every subpackage in the script? Then what's the point of importing the `scipy` package?

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071715/why-does-from-scipy-import-spatial-work-while-scipy-spatial-doesnt-work-after; I'm sure there are still more occurrences of this question elsewhere on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

From the `scipy` doc:

> Using any of these subpackages requires an explicit import.  For example,
>       `import scipy.cluster`.

or `from scipy import cluster`.

There isn't much point to doing a simple

```
import scipy
```

Look at the `site-packages/scipy/__init__.py` file for more details.  Compare it with the `numpy` init.

`numpy` is an integrated package, `scipy` is a collection of loosely integrated packages.  `numpy` is the basic numeric package that everyone uses.  The `scipy` subpackages are relatively independent of each other.  I can load and use `sparse` without knowning anything about the `signal` or `integrate` packages.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for which modules are imported in a python package is defined in the `__init__.py` file in the package directory. You can `locate` the scipy directory or find this using `ipython`, `import scipy` and call `scipy?` with questionmark to get the path. By default it seems `scipy` only imports numpy. The signal module is a directory of scripts, which includes its own `__init__.py` so you need the `scipy.signal.lti` syntax.

You could edit `__init__.py` as outlined in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852811/python-how-to-import-from-all-modules-in-dir) which would reduce the boilerplate imports, although probably not recommended as it would yield code which is not portable and may result in name clashes.