# Strange import scipy in Eclipse with Pydev, no auto completion

Tags: python, eclipse, optimization, scipy, pydev

I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize` for my algorithm. I use scipy 0.16.1, Eclpise LUNA and PyDev.

When my code is:

```
import scipy as sp
optim = sp.optimize.minimize(func,x0 = x0,args = (X,Y,Z))
print optim
print optim.x
```

The `print optim` works fine, but I got a warning underlying `optimize` as: `Undefined variable from import: optimize`. And I got an error when running the code `print optim.x AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'`

However, when I change my code to:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as spo
optim = spo.minimize(func,x0 = x0,args = (X,Y,Z))
print optim
print optim.x
```

It works fine. But, I do not have auto completion when I type `print optim.` for `x`

So here are my questions:

1. Why `import scipy as sp` with `sp.optimize.minimize` gives a warning?
2. Why there is no auto completion for `optim.`?

Comment: The problem seems to be within Eclipse/Pydev, as the code works as expected! I see the same here for scipy 0.14 with Eclipse Kepler and PyDev 2.3...

Comment: @flyingmouse It might not be obvious, but this question is a duplicate.  See the question that I marked it as duplicating, along with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071715/why-does-from-scipy-import-spatial-work-while-scipy-spatial-doesnt-work-after; there are probably still more questions in stackoverflow that are basically about the same issue.  In short, you *must* explicitly import `scipy.optimize`.  If you only `import scipy`, the `optimize` subpackage is not imported.