# Scipy optimize not loaded

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

It seems as if I have to import scipy optimize explicitly to get it.
An example:
If I do

```
 import scipy as sp
 sp.optimize.somefunction()
```

I get an `AttributeError`. 
But if I do

```
 import scipy as sp
 from scipy import optimize
 sp.optimize.somefunction()
```

Everything works fine.

Is this desired behaviour? How do I enforce python to load the whole namespace of scipy by doing `import scipy as sp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.  The import directives in `scipy` don't allow that.  By design it is modular.  You have to use the `from scipy import optimize` kind of statements.

With `from scipy import optimize` you can then use `optimize.somefunction()`.

This has been raised a number of times before.  A good duplicate is

[Why does from scipy import spatial work, while scipy.spatial doesn't work after import scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071715/why-does-from-scipy-import-spatial-work-while-scipy-spatial-doesnt-work-after)